# Bernoulli’s equation problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find an explicit family of solutions for the Bernoulli’s equation $x^2y’+2xy=5y^4$ using a substitution.

I worked out this problem but I’m not sure if I’m getting the right answer. If someone could check my work I would greatly appreciate it![image: The image contains my work]

......

Comment: Looks correct to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, the left side is itself already a complete derivative,
$$
(x^2y)'=5y^4=5x^{-8}(x^2y)^4.
$$
This now is separable and gives for $u=x^2y$
$$
\frac{du}{u^4}=\frac{5dx}{x^8}\implies \frac1{u^3}=\frac{15}{7x^7}+C
$$
which is equivalent to your result.